# How to onclick outside an input element which is inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It maybe easy but i can't think anything to find the way when i click outside the textbox to alert something in javascript BUT when i click inside the text nothing to happen.The input text is inside the div element.

So,let's assume that my html is like bellow:

```
<div id="myone" onclick="javascript: myfunc();">
<input type="text" id="myInput"></input>
</div>

function myfunc()
{
alert('ok');
}
```

How to change that?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use this condition. [e.target !== this](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

It is often useful to compare `event.target` to this in order to determine if the **event** is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in **event delegation**, when events bubble.

Use it inside your click function like this and see it in action:

```js
$('.divover').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this) return;
  thefunc();
});


var thefunc = function myfunc() {
  alert('ok');
}
```

```css
.divover {
  padding: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='divover'>somelabel:
  <span><input type="text"  class="as" name="forename"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myone');
var funct = function(){
    var input = div.querySelector("#myInput");
    return false;
};

div.onclick = funct;
```

Comment: can you give me an jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you but when you click inside text it is the same with outside.I dont want this i want when click in text nothing to happen

Comment: Then I don't see the point of making the div clickable as opposed to making the input clickable.  If you make the div clickable, clicking ANYWHERE in the div will fire the onclick function, even on text.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, if you do this carefully.

```
<div id="myone" onclick="javascript: myfunc();">
//your stuff in the clickable division.
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;">
<!--Adjust this division in such a way that, it comes inside your clickable division--><input     
type="text" id="myInput"></input>
</div>



//Your script function/code here
function myfunc()
{
alert('ok');
}
```

Comment: What's happening when you try to do that ... ?